# What's the state machine of DriverNode?

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm looking at the hokuyo node.
As far as I understood the class HokuyoDriver extends driver_base::Driver which provides the methods

- doOpen
- doClose
- doStart
- doStop

The class HokuyoNode instead extends driver_base::DriverNode. However in the code I cannot find how this node calls the methods doXYZ of the HokuyoDriver.
In other words I would like to understand the (implicit or explicit) state machine of driver_base::DriverNode and when the methods doXYZ are called.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33717/what%27s-the-state-machine-of-drivernode?/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-05-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is a bit hard to follow. As best I can tell, `driver_base` implements three states:

- Closed: not connected to the device.
- Opened: device is open, but not streaming data.
- Running: device is streaming data.

There is some confusion about the names: some comments refer to the Opened state as Stopped (following `doStop()`), but I think they the same.

The dynamic reconfigure parameters are coded with a bit mask, indicating what state changes are necessary for updating each parameter. That is a useful idea, which can easily be implemented without using `driver_base` explicitly.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2